# Amazon ECS docker logs since start with Log Configuration set as default

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, docker, logging, amazon-ecs

> I have a docker service running on `Amazon ECS` and I want to fetch the logs since the service sarted which was around 4 months ago. Since I keep deploying to it, the current container only shows logs for last 2 days which was when I deployed last.

I have tried the following things -

```
/var/lib/docker/containers/<container-id>/<container-id>-json.log - This shows logs for last 2 days only
```

I checked `/var/lib/ecs`, there is nothing useful there.

There aren't any application logs in the project folder also.

Where else can I find this information? Any help would be appreciated